# remap caps lock to right alt

Tags: keyboard, xorg, keyboard-layout, capslock

I've had a look at other questions, as well as the xkb options list (/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst), but can't seem to find a way to map the caps lock key to act as another right alt key.

(On a German keyboard right alt is needed to get to square brackets, and having the otherwise useless caps lock set this way makes for way less hand-cramping typing.)

Answer (score 1):

Found this

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = ISO_Level3_Shift"
```

as an [answer on Superuser](https://superuser.com/a/138757/306142).